# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. and You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I have installed Xcode from app store for updated version.Now i am installing cocoapods. For installation i used sudo gem install cocoapods it is showing this error

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    
        current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210422-1825-1sq5o2c.rb extconf.rb
    creating Makefile
    
    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
    make "DESTDIR=" clean
    
    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.5.1/ext/json/ext/generator
    make "DESTDIR="
    compiling generator.c
    In file included from generator.c:1:
    In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby.h:33:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
    #include "ruby/config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [generator.o] Error 1
    
    make failed, exit code 2
    
    Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/json-2.5.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/json-2.5.1/gem_make.out.
```

when i use gem install cocoapods then it will show error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... 
(Gem::FilePermissionError)
        You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory how to fix
```

it i have tried so many tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use System ruby (the one in /Library/Ruby) as macOS restricts access to it.

Try installing Ruby using Rbenv, following this guide : https://gorails.com/setup/osx/11.0-big-sur (follow the **Installing Ruby** part).

After installation, quit your terminal (Command + q), open again and try install cocoapods again, hope this helps.